# Java: transform document to an existing document: merge?

Tags: java, xml, transform

I cached an XSLT and apply it to several documents in a loop. Each result has the same format.

```
DocumentResult allResults = new DocumentResult();

for (iter = requests.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
  transformer.transform(new DocumentSource(request), allResults);
}

return allResults;
```

Although the code doesn't work it should display what I'm trying to attempt: requests having the same `ID` value should be merged or appended otherwise.

Is there a way to implement this without having to perform the merge manually?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at StreamResult (examples [here](http://www.ling.helsinki.fi/kit/2004k/ctl257/JavaXSLT/Ch05.html) and [here](http://www.ling.helsinki.fi/kit/2004k/ctl257/JavaXSLT/Ch05.html)). If you create the appropriate ByteArrayOutputStream at the start you should be able to append from the StreamResult).

Comment: how to avoid start/end root tags?

Comment: It wasn't clear that you want them removed :-) You will have to write the logic to (say) extract the children of the root. Depending on what you want eitehr a stream or SAX should be appropriate

Answer (score 0):

I would implement `org.xml.sax.ContentHandler` passes all the incoming SAX events to the underlying content handler for `SAXResult`, and skips all unnecessary events (`startDocument`, `endDocument`, and `startElement` for root tags.